# Xamarin Notification Service Extension Problems

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have several issues with implementing this extensions.

1. I get the service to run in one project but then in another it doesn't fire at all.
2. I get the service to fire on some devices and not on others.
3. The service sometimes works in pulling a NSUrl call but fails on the identical call later on.

I have read the post:
[Xamarin Notification Service Extension issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428243/xamarin-notification-service-extension-issue)

Is there a better solution than reverting to Objective-C and replacing the appex and resigning?  Also, has anyone else experienced the inconsistencies with devices? Any reason why it works for one project and then has trouble working in another?

Comment: Hey, I noticed you also posted something in the Xamarin forms, too.  Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after a LOT of tries.  It only works in release mode.

It has to do with a bug in Debug mode.  Details are here (in the comments).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=vswin#working-with-service-extensions